# how read vaadin grid header column key stored?

Tags: vaadin

hello in debug mode i need this property but have private method

```
getGrid().getHeaderRows().stream()
  .findAny()
  .get()
  .getCells()
  .get(0).getColumn().columnKey
```

exist other property for read this value?

tnx

Answer (score 4):

Why do you think you need to get the column key?

Just set it when you create the Grid column. Example

```
grid.addColumn(ClubRecord::getName)
    .setHeader(getTranslation("Name"))
    .setSortable(true)
    .setAutoWidth(true)
    .setKey("club_name");
```